# Trying to build lambda tree

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I'm trying to build an expression that must create query of type WHERE IN ()
For IN I must check if value exist in a list, so my expression looks like:

```
long loKey = 2;
List<long> loKeys = new List<long>();
loKeys.Add(loKey);

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "t");
var constantExpression = Expression.Constant((List<long>)loKeys, typeof(List<long>));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
    typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type, typeof(bool)),
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(parameter, "ID"),
        constantExpression
    ),
    parameter
);
resultQuery = resultQuery.Provider.CreateQuery(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable), 
        "Where",
        new Type[] { type },
        resultQuery.Expression,
        lambda
    ) 
);
```

So the idea is that `field ID` must exist in list `loKeys`, but I'm getting an error:

> Additional information: The binary operator Equal is not defined for
>   the types 'System.Int64' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]'.

On Expression.Lambda -> MakeGenericType

Comment: Why don't use something like `query.Where(entity => keysEnumerable.Contains(entity.Id))`, where `keysEnumerable` is `IEnumerable<PrimaryKeyType>`?

Comment: Because my query doesn`t have type , so i can`t use .Where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are trying to build something like this:

```
t => loKeys.Contains(t.ID)
```

The only thing you need to consider is that actually `Contains` is a static extension method defined in `Enumerable` class:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable), 
        "Contains", 
        new[] { typeof(long) },
        Expression.Constant(loKeys),
        Expression.Property(parameter, "ID")
    ),
    parameter
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it the exception is thrown because of the part:
    Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(parameter, "ID"),
    constantExpression
    ),
In which you're comparing the constantExpressions, which is a generic list, with a parameter of type long (i guess, doesn't say what type the parameter is), maybe instead of Equals you should use Method call for "Contains" and see if the parameter is in the list (like Dennis suggested).

Comment: Yes ,yes i thing about the same , but Expression doesn`t have method Contains .. so the real question is what method can be used instead of Equal ?

Comment: @HarryBirimirski if `type` is always `ICollection`, you can use Expression.Call and pass it `ICollection.Contains()` as methodInfo